# Prevent closing of context menu when showing an alert dialog in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, dialog, contextmenu, alert

I have a context menu, which contains a CustomMenuItem with some controls. When clicking a button, a dialog shows and the context menu hides automatically. Here is the problem: I would like to prevent the closing of the context menu when the dialog shows. How can I solve this problem?

I already have tracked done the event. When the dialog opens, a FocusUngrabEvent.FOCUS_UNGRAB event is fired, which is handled in PopupWindow. I already tried to add an EventFilter and EventHandler to the context menu for FocusUngrabEvent.FOCUS_UNGRAB and consume the event, but that does not help.

Here an SSCCE demonstrating this problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PimaryStage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // The button which shows the dialog.
        Button button = new Button("Some Button");
        button.setOnAction((event)-> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Some Text");

            alert.show();
        });

        // Custom menu item which contains the button.
        CustomMenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem(button);
        menuItem.setHideOnClick(false);

        // Context menu.
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);

        // Label.
        Label label = new Label("Click here to open the context menu.");
        label.setContextMenu(menu);

        // Set the scene and show the stage.
        Scene scene  = new Scene(label, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: please google on something that goes like setoncloserequests on window in javafx. you will find your solution, after you can delete the question, it has been asked here before, so you will likely see the answer here

Comment: @checkMyProfile Could you give me a link to the mentioned stackoverflow question? I could not find it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@FXML
public void autoShow() {
    contextmenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            e.consume();
        }
    });


}
```

Place the above method in your controller class and then call it from the initialize method in your controller class:

```
@Override 
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    autoShow();

}
```

Comment: If I add `menu.setOnAction(Event::consume)`  in the above SSCCE, the context menu still closes after the alert dialog is shown.